# Replacing fonts in Powerpoint view does not replace font

Tags: powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint template.  When this template was passed off It included some special fonts that I needed to remove because it was throwing warnings when users opened them up.

When I use the "replace fonts" feature it does not remove the font.  I deal a lot with the XML properties of these templates because some of the content is generated dynamically when a report is run.  I can still see in the slides the font is present

`<a:buFont typeface="Poppins"/>` the other is `<a:buFont typeface="Noto Sans Symbols"/>`

Which both appear to be bullet list fonts?  There are no lists in the view though...

Removing it from the XML itself is not an option because when I update the template again it will override that and given that doesn't happen often I will have forgotten all about this. I need to fix this in the template so I can then export it out.

I have edited all the text I can see to either Ariel or Calibri but this `Poppins` font is still in there and I have no idea how to get it out.

Specifics are

1. Powerpoint version is 16.36
2. The program is actually Powerpoint for Mac (if that matters)

If anyone solved a similar issue and can give me some direction it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The **buFont** tag means that font is being used for a bullet rather than actual text. Probably a text level somewhere uses a custom bullet specced with this font. Each content or text placeholder can have up to 9 text levels, you may hove to create 9 levels using **Home>Indent More** to find the right one.

Start with the Slide Master (View>Slide Master>the larger thumbnail at the top). Then check each placeholder on each Layout (smaller thumbnails below the Master). Finally, check each multilevel placeholder on each slide, in case this was added with local formatting.

My go-to technique is to unzip the presentation into the XML files and do a find and replace on them. That's the quickest way to replace fonts, which can be tucked away in all kinds of obscure places in a presentation. On a Mac, this takes a bit of preparation to avoid problems caused by the OS. If you regularly create PowerPoint files, it may be worth it to set this up. Here's my article on this: [OOXML Hacking: Editing in macOS](http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2015/11/xml-hacking-editing-in-os-x/). Look for the part about using a USB or network drive that is set to *not* create hidden **.DS_Store** files. Then use a text editor like BBEdit to do multi-file find and replace operations on the font name.

Comment: Ya the problem is every time I update this I need to remember to remove it from the XML.  We use the XML values to actually rebuild some parts of the templates in our application based on user Data, so I can't just remove it from the XML file and forget it, because next time they want to add a slide in I do the process  you talk about above (zip/unzip) and that font value will be in there.  I'll try finding though using your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you need to revise the templates in addition to the presentations they're based on.

Comment: Ah yes, I think I maybe used the wrong lingo,  I am trying to remove this from the templates, not the presentation.  I need to remove it from the source.

Answer (score 0):

I have PowerPoint 16.39 on my MacBook Pro. Try to click on **PowerPoint** in the upper left. Then **Preferences**, then the **Save** icon. At the bottom you'll have **Font Embedding**. If you **un-check** this option, it should not save fonts to the template anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately, I already did this and the font is still staying in, god what a waste of time Powerpoint is.

Comment: @RockwellRice - Maybe try `Command + Spacebar` then type in **FONT BOOK**. Once it's opened, locate "Poppins" & right-click on it. Does it give you the option to **DISABLE** and or **DELETE**?

Comment: `Command + Spacebar` opens up Font Book on my own computer.  I need to remove this from the PPT because when users download it the likely won't have this font.  I have it actually so not an issue for me personally. Am I misunderstanding something?  Doing what you said did not open up anything in the powerpoint.

Comment: @RockwellRice - my guess is that if you've already removed it from your Mac, then you should be good to save as a template. Then try to open it on somebody else's computer to see if there's anymore problems.

Comment: I can still see it present in the XML though

Comment: @RockwellRice - is it causing a problem on another person's computer?

Comment: Yes, when other people download it they are getting the error.  These reports will be downloaded by people online, clients of the application, and so I need to make sure the fonts are basic. However, when they designed/created the template and passed it to us they had included many google fonts and such that I am having a hard time removing.  I got some, but the code above persists.

Comment: @RockwellRice - can you try deleting the XML file for "Poppins" & see if that helps you? Open Finder & go to **Macintosh HD/Applications**. Then `right-click` on the PowerPoint app & pick **Show Package Contents** near the top. Then navigate to **Contents/Resources/Office Themes/Theme Fonts** and `right-click` on Poppins.xml & move it to the trash.

Comment: Poppins is not in there

Comment: I downloaded the "Poppins" Google font onto my Mac. To add it, I used Font Book as described above. Then I opened PowerPoint & could see it in the choices of fonts at the top. Then I went back to Font Book & removed it. I closed PowerPoint, reopened it & it was gone.

Comment: ok I'm not sure you understand the issue I am trying to solve, maybe I could explain better.  I need to remove it from the XML in the template, I need to remove it from the very source.  I don't think what you are describing does this.  Can you verify that it removed it from the template XML?

Comment: Sure, I will have a look. How are you opening the XML & I'll take a peek.

Comment: Basically the process described in John Korchok answer above.  I copy it, change it to a zip and then extract the items

Comment: I just now read John's answer. He's a pro for sure. I clicked his link & it turns out I already have **BBEdit** on my MacBook. So I didn't go through all the zipping & stuff to view the **XML** files in the **PowerPoint** file. More good news is that "**poppins**" did **not** appear anywhere. You should be able to grab **BBEdit** from the **AppStore** & give it a shot, too, just to make sure. It's free for 30 days.

Comment: Ya but that is just another way of removing it from the XML afterward.  I need to remove it from the very source (the PPT itself) so I don't have to remember to do that every time the PPT gets an update.

Comment: I didn't use BBEdit to delete anything. I only used it to search.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219690/discussion-between-rockwell-rice-and-joe-beck).

Comment: I'm in there now